# how to insert data to table by store procedure with session value?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

This is a stored procedure in mysql database.

I tried mysql_query($connection, "CALL xyz")
but shows me error.

by store procedure I want to insert data to table

I want insert data from session values in my php page.

Comment: Pls share the exact error message with us. Although, I guess the problem is that you failed to provide any parameters to the stored procedure. This one has excellent documentation, you just need to read it.

Comment: Have you used session_start() before trying to use a session value in the stored procedure? Be aware that the old mysql_* extension which you're using is deprecated in version 5.5 of PHP (the current version) and is being removed from version 7 (the next version). You need migrate over to using either the mysqli_* extension or PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedures can be called using the `CALL` keyword. The first procedure you list would be called with parameters similar to this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');
$mysqli->query("CALL p_maintain_user('i', 123, 123, 'password', 'a')");
```

The [PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php) provides an article with more information on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It works. How can I edit or delete in this table by the procedure call ?

Comment: @user3518270 Glad it works, edit or delete is the same except replace the first `'i'` parameter with `'u'` (for update) or `'d'` (for delete).

Comment: @user3518270 what errors are you receiving when deleting? Looking at the above code, deleting doesn't actually delete the data but instead sets the `Status` field to `i`, is it doing this?

Comment: Thanks Once again...I got it.